# Read txt file from line to line to list?

Tags: c#, .net, text-files

need some function that will return List with lines of txt file (ex. from 10 line to 25 line).
Any solutions? All my tries met with failure.

Comment: Post the code you have so we can see what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Retrieve 10 lines from Somefile.txt, starting from line 1
string filePath = "C:\\Somefile.txt";
int startLine = 1;
int lineCount = 10;
var fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                .Skip((startLine-1))
                .Take(lineCount);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use LINQ and [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) which enumerates over file lines (internally it uses [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)):

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(path).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
List<string> fileLines = new List<string>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       fileLines.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines().ToList();
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++){
if( i >= startline && i <= endline) LinesFromStartToEnd.Add( lines[i] );// same string list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file isn't too large you can do it with linq:

```
int start = 10;
int end = 25;    
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(start - 1).Take(end - start + 1).ToList();
```